# TPascal, Stack Overflow, Recursion

Tags: pascal

My program should inverse a string (ex. for Hello world returns dlrow olleH) and it works only for strings smaller than 20 characters. For 20 or more i get "Error 202 Stack overflow". Thank you :)

```
Program Inv;
var S, A: String;
n: integer;

Function I(X: String; z: integer):String;
    begin
        if z=1 then I:=X[z] else
        I:=X[z]+I(X, z-1);
    end;

begin
    write ('Enter your text: ');
    readln (S);
    n:=length(S);
    A:=I(S, n);
    writeln (A);
    readln;
end.
```

Comment: Every nested function call allocates at least 256 bytes (may be even 512). You should be able to process more characters if you declare
`Function I(const X: String; z: integer):String;` 
Remember: Stack space with TP7 is maximal 64KB.

Comment: Yes, now works for a max. of  29 characters. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are *required* to show a recursive solution, you're usually better to sticking with iteration<sup>(a)</sup>. Recursion uses an often-limited resource (the stack) to weave its magic and is often the cause of crashes when you exceed that limit.

Iterative solutions tend to be far less restrictive, such as the code below:

```pascal
program PaxCode;

Function reverse(inp_str: string) : string;
    var out_str : string    = '';
    var idx     : integer   = 1;

    begin
        while (idx <= length(inp_str)) do
        begin
            out_str := inp_str[idx] + out_str;
            idx := idx + 1
        end;
        reverse := out_str
    end;

var test_str: string = 'My hovercraft is full of eels and they will not let me drive it';

begin
    writeln(test_str);
    writeln(reverse(test_str))
end.
```

As you can see, the output is correct, and not limited to twenty (or twenty-nine) characters:

```
My hovercraft is full of eels and they will not let me drive it
ti evird em tel ton lliw yeht dna slee fo lluf si tfarcrevoh yM
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The *best* areas for recursion are those where each level removes a sizable proportion of the solution space. For example, binary searches remove fully 50% of the remaining solution space on every level so you could search through a structure holding four billion entries with just thirty-two levels, since `232` is a touch above 4.2 billion.

Something like reversing a 400-character string will take, ..., let me think, oh yes, ***400*** levels. That won't necessarily end well :-)